# Product is missing Attibute Text property

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, quoteitem

I have the following in my custom module:

```
$product = $quote_item->getProduct();
```

If I then do this I see the product id:

```
var_dump($product->getId());
```

This though gives me null:

```
var_dump($product->getAttributeText('manufacturer'));
```

But this gives me the manaufacturer:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($quote_item->getProductId());

var_dump($product->getAttributeText('manufacturer'));
```

I can't use the second option becuase I am adding to some existing code which I do not want to break. Taking the first example how can I access the AttributeText property and why in my case is it empty?

Comment: Have you already found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add custom attributes to quote items, you have to declare them first.

Add this to your modules `config.xml`global section:

```
    <sales>
        <quote>
            <item>
                <product_attributes>
                    <manufacturer />
                </product_attributes>
            </item>
        </quote>
    </sales>
```

Comment: So does this force the custom attribute to be included when i call getProduct on the quote item?

Comment: Yes, this is perfect code, you will get custom attribute value after this code.

Comment: @AlanA Yes, this attribute should be included in `getProduct()` data. Please let me know if it works for you :)